# spring boot 1.3.1 devtools hot reload not work if your project name is spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot 1.3.1.RELEASE, used devtools.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Now I add some code in controller method, e.g.

```
logger.info("delete {} ", name);
```

but in eclipse console, nothing output, and access this url , the new add logger did not output. So why is so? why hot reload not work?

I found something could explain this phenomenon. Because my project name is `spring-boot`, and run `Application` class in eclispe you could see:
[image]

you could see after Application name appended `(1)`

I don't know what's this mean.

After rename project name to anything else(e.g. spring-boot-reservation), now I found devtools could work normally.
And this time the number after Application name is changed to 2,
[image]